# Storing command line arguments in variables

Tags: c#

I want to store the command line input separated by space to be stored in different variables. For example, if input is `0 1 2 3`,then `a=0,b=1,c=2,d=3`.
The code is as follows.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Enter L,D,S,C");
            Console.Read();
            int l = Convert.ToInt32(args[0]);
            int d = Convert.ToInt32(args[1]);
            int s = Convert.ToInt32(args[2]);
            int c = Convert.ToInt32(args[3]);



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to grab the command-line arguments, but the application itself is asking for interactive input.  Which one do you want to use?

Comment: And how you are going to use this generated variable later?

Comment: `args` is from the command line: `ConsoleApplication1 0 1 2 3`. If you need to parse the input from `Console.ReadLine()` you need to store it in a string variable, split it, then convert it to integers.

Comment: I will do some mathematical calculations on these l,d,s,c variables.

Comment: don't we have something like it is in C++ where we write..cin>>l>>d>>s>>c ?

Comment: no, this is definitely a different language

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Console.ReadLine()` and then the string you got can easily split it by using the function `String.Split()`, in your case you will use `String.Split(' ')` which will return an array of strings and will split using the spaces

For more information for the split function:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Console.ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and also you should store returning value into some variable:

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();

int[] numbers = line.Split(' ').Select(x => (int)x).ToArray();
```

Also as David said these are not `command line arguments`, these are user inputs.I write like that because as i see you are trying to use Console.Read, if you want learn how to use command line arguments in C# you should take a look at here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb20e19t.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This will read each key stroke one by one:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Enter L,D,S,C");
        char ch = (char) Console.Read();
        string a = ch.ToString();
        ch = (char) Console.Read();
        string b = ch.ToString();
        .... 


    }
```

Or simply read the entire input an perform a split on the comma:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Enter L,D,S,C");
        string line = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] ltrs = line.Split(',');


    }
```